# Bluetooth Headsets wont play audio and record at the same time

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I'm attempting to use a pair of wireless headsets. They have microphone capability. I've freshly reformatted my computers because of this issue.

Here's what is happening. After pairing the Bluetooth 4.0 headphones, I can hear audio. However, to test this, if I attempt to listen to music and record my voice at the same time, audio cuts out as if on pause. Once the microphone releases control, audio continues where it left off.

Multiple computers, multiple USB adapters (using different drivers) and multiple Bluetooth headsets. Windows 10 is the only common link.

As you might tell, this makes the headsets completely useless for things like Discord, Skype or other VOIP where both are expected at the same time. Additionally, I'll get stuttering like a buffered stream is not getting data.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just to confirm, you've tested this on computers running other operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, or older versions of Windows (8, 7, Vista, etc), and it *did* work on those?

Comment: WHile I attempted to get it to work on Ubuntu Live (wasn't about to overwrite my OS for this test), it would not pair properly. I could not get sound out of it for a different reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon discussion with the manufacture of the headsets, they provided a new bluetooth USB dongle. This being of their own, I figure it works just fine.

I found out, however, that standard Bluetooth profiles do not support "Hands Free" and the more quality audio profile for music. If you want to record and hear at the same time, you must use the driver/device for "Hands Free". This will permit the audio to play at the same time that you talk.

As stated, the quality of the audio is sub par. Built for hands free calls. In order to support audio at high quality and microphone, you need headphones that are "Faststream" capable. This is new to me. Guess it's bluetooth with crappy audio quality while VOIPing on a game, or proprietary wireless dongle for your headset. (Sadly, 2.4ghz dongles wont work as it seems the 802.11 wireless router I have interferes with it. Along with my neighbors.)